Improving runtime of graph computation
I am using pycel to create a graph of an excel calculation. Essentially I have a cell that performs some calculation:
E.g., =AVERAGE(I2:X2)
Which in turn is a function of other cells in other worksheets
E.g., I2 = sheet2!A1/sheet3!B6
And these cells can be functions of other cells etc. pycel builds a graph of this process using networkx.
My goal is to run some simulations. I create sample values for some of the cells, pass them through my graph and check what the target cell value is (=AVERAGE(I2:X2) in this case).
My actual graph has around 6000 nodes and 8000 edges. When I pass in ~10 samples, the computations take around 5 minutes. But when I try over 500 samples, the runtime becomes horrible (over 4-5 hours atleast, I have never let it finish).
I have some dotproduct calculations in my actual excel and I believe these might be causing some redundant calculations because I am seeing output such as:
Range Correlation Matrix!B2:I2 evaluated to '((36.305348, 19.746452, 89.413364, 87.434721, 19.308097, 90.679385, 3.561042, 15.810838),)'
Range Correlation Matrix!B2:I2 evaluated to '((36.305348, 19.746452, 89.413364, 87.434721, 19.308097, 90.679385, 3.561042, 15.810838),)'
Range Correlation Matrix!B2:I2 evaluated to '((36.305348, 19.746452, 89.413364, 87.434721, 19.308097, 90.679385, 3.561042, 15.810838),)'
Range Correlation Matrix!B2:I2 evaluated to '((36.305348, 19.746452, 89.413364, 87.434721, 19.308097, 90.679385, 3.561042, 15.810838),)'

Several times.
So is there a way to address the runtime issues? Since each pass through the graph is independent, I think this should be highly parallelizable but I am unsure of how to go about this.
Previously I was using xlwings to insert data and track the target cell value and this worked. It took around 4 hours to run 10000 samples but I thought that by moving the calculations outside of excel, I should see some improvements but the opposite seems to be true.

Hey Ben.  I built most of the current version of PyCel.  NetworkX builds the graph, but the traversal and calculations is all Python. The calcs should be able to be multithreaded, but you would need to manage the threading yourself. Also ExcelCompiler.trim_graph() might help with performance.

Thanks Stephen! I am looking into the trimp_graph() method now. Just an initial question: I manually specify input_addrs, output_addrs and these cells are then removed from the graph?
I have been playing around with the multiprocess library but without much success. I think I will just use GNU Parallel with some bash scripts and try my luck that way.
